# Setting a Popup Buttons Value from Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to set an external applications settings with an applescript. I currently have

```
tell application "System Events"
     tell process "Pro Tools"
         click menu item "Save Copy In..." of menu "File" of menu bar 1
         tell pop up button 4 of window "Save Copy In..."
             click
             set value to "AIFF"
         end tell
      end tell
 end tell
```

But nothing happens at the `set value` point. Any help would be gratefully received! Attached is a screenshot of where I'm stuck at.

[image]

Comment: In most cases the three dots `...` are actually **one** character called Horizontal Ellipsis (`⌥;` on the US Keyboard). And is the title of the window really `Save Copy In…` ?

Comment: Sorry. Wasn't very clear. It all works up until the set value. And then nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to wait until the "Save Copy In..." window appears.  Try this code, which adds a delay loop looking for the window.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Pro Tools"
        tell menu bar 1's menu "File"
            click menu item "Save Copy In..."
        end tell

        repeat until (exists window "Save Copy In...")
            delay 0.1
        end repeat

        tell window "Save Copy In..."'s pop up button 4
            click
            -- the menu does not appear inthe PUB's view heirarchy until after it's clicked
            tell menu 1
                click menu item "AIFF" -- 'pick' should work too
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi Ted. I've actually already added in the delay. The scripts gets to the point shown in the screenshot but just fails on the 'AIFF' select. Using your method I get this again `System Events got an error: Can’t get menu 1 of pop up button 4 of window "Save Copy In..." of process "Pro Tools". Invalid index.`

Comment: Ok, so try this as a diagnostic. Right after the script clicks the popup button, add in the line `entire contents`.This will give you a list of all the UI elements that the script sees at that point. Does it start with `menu 1` or something else??

Comment: that returns `{}`

Comment: put a one second delay before the `entire contents` line, to make sure that the menu is open.

Comment: hmm. same result

Comment: But the popup button menu appears? That's... weird. I'd say it was impossible if it weren't happening. I'll need to think about this a minute.

Comment: @Chris Barrett: As best I can tell, this is a problem with the core implementation of the standard NSSavePanel; it doesn't respond to accessibility commands correctly. I mean, UIElementBrowser sees them, but System Events doesn't, and I'm not quite certain where the fault lies. I take it ProTools isn't directly scriptable?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Only workaround i've found is to add a `keystroke` command to jump to the value then `enter` but it has a 5s delay for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a short delay to make sure the menu is available and rather than setting the `value` `pick` the `menu item`.

```
tell application "System Events"
     tell process "Pro Tools"
         click menu item "Save Copy In..." of menu "File" of menu bar 1
         tell pop up button 4 of window "Save Copy In..."
             click
             delay 0.2
             pick menu item "AIFF" of menu 1
         end tell
      end tell
 end tell
```

The command `pick` is not documented, it's a synonym of `click`.

Comment: Throws this unfortunately `System Events got an error: Can’t get menu 1 of pop up button 4 of window "Save Copy In..." of process "Pro Tools". Invalid index.`

Comment: GUI scripting Pro Tools is hopeless. Does `set value` work?

Comment: Using `set value to "AIFF"` doesn't error. But doesn't work either :-(

Comment: Some of the UI elements Avid uses don't conform to the Cocoa standard. Do you have an UI element inspector? Or log the properties, attributes and actions of the popup button. GUI scripting is a lot of trial & error.

Comment: Thanks vadian. I have been using UI browser and as its opening the menu OK its just the select thats not working.